# EXCEL VLOOKUP Parameter aproximate

Tags: excel, vlookup

In my workbook I have my matrix in an own table because I use it in various table where I calculate some value to search in the matrix that aren't always precicly a value in the matrix, if these value is close to a specific value in the matrix the result is close to a value in the row before, that is far away from the right row. How do I soluce this problem, I tried with

```
if(isnv(vlookup(my_search_value, my_matrix, 2, false), vlookup(my_search_value, my_matrix, 2, true))
```

without exit.

And

```
iferror(vlookup(my_search_value, my_matrix, 2, false), vlookup(my_search_value, my_matrix, 2, true)))"
```

still I get the line before.

Comment: So are you trying to interpolate for a given value such as 57 when the entries are 50 and 60? If so then you have to do an interpolation finding the nearest values above and below, then the resulting values and then the ratio to give the result. A nice little exercise.

Comment: Hi Scott, you are absolute right.

Comment: @Scott, how do I do that interpolation?

Comment: Hi Scott, it can happen, that the searched Value exist also as entry in the Matrix, which has entry from 0 to 337,5, it is this table https://www.rechner.club/masseinheit/himmelsrichtung-winkel-grad-tabelle.

Comment: 180º should VLOOKUP(180,Matrix,2,TRUE) return "S", but for any value close to 180 I get SSO, that is 157,5
 °, the entry before.